# How to get average of every n rows and store it in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to take average of every 10000 rows of specific column say [col1], and store it in new column ?

i tried using the following code.

```
df['Average'] = df['col1'].rolling(10000).mean()
```

But it take average of from 0 to 10000 and then 1 to 10000

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom grouper with [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), then [`groupby.transform('mean')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
import numpy as np

N = 10_000
df['Average'] = (df['col1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N)
                           .transform('mean')
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you. without using transform worked for me.